# Merge Arbitrary Amount of Arrays into Single Array?

Tags: arrays, json, file, concatenation, jq

I have a series of JSON files that I've been working with via [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). Each file consists of an array of dictionaries, e.g.

- file1.json: `[{ "id": 1 }]`
- file2.json: `[{ "id": 2 }]`

The only command I have found which successfully merges all input files into one output array is:

```sh
jq --slurp '.[0] + .[1]' file1.json file2.json
```

This command outputs `[{ "id": 1 }, { "id": 2 }]`, as expected.

I'm writing a shell script which is expected to merge a variable set of files into a single JSON array as an output. My script will execute something like:

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.json' | xargs jq 'FILTER'
```

This should invoke `jq` like `jq 'FILTER' file1.json file2.json ...`.

Is there a feature that I'm missing that will take all input files and first merge them into one contiguous list of objects without having to rewrite the filter to something like `.[0] + .[1] + .[2] ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Given:

*1.json*

```
[{ "id": 1 }]
```

*2.json*

```
[{ "id": 2 }]
```

*3.json*

```
[{ "id": 3 }]
```

Then this command:

```
jq --slurp 'map(.[])' 1.json 2.json 3.json
```

Returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

Or simply:

```
jq --slurp 'flatten' 1.json 2.json 3.json
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Both `flatten` and `map(.[])` work, provided that `--slurp` is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to avoid the `-s` option, especially if your version of jq supports `inputs`, as do all versions >= 1.5.

In any case, if your version of jq supports `inputs`, you could write:

```
jq -n '[inputs[]]' 1.json 2.json 3.json # etc
```

or whichever variant meets your needs.

Otherwise, you could simply write:

```
jq -s add 1.json 2.json 3.json # etc
```

### Note on `flatten`

`flatten` itself is ruthless:

```
$ jq flatten <<< '[[[1], [[[[2]]]]]]'
[1,2]
```

`flatten(1)` is less so.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `[inputs[0]]` to respect all files, however, `jq -n "[inputs[]]"` seems to work.